# How to put a trait bound for web_sys::HtmlElement::from function

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

With `e_text` of type `web_sys::HtmlDivElement` and `e_button` of type `web_sys::HtmlButtonElement` this function builds a Closure to a on_click callback. Compiles and runs ok.

```
let a = buildCbClosure(web_sys::HtmlElement::from(e_text));

fn buildCbClosure(mut e : web_sys::HtmlElement) -> Closure<dyn FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent)> {
    let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
        handleButtonClick(&event);
        e.set_text_content(Some("Text - Klik"));
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
    a
}

e_button.set_onclick(Some(a.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
```

Next step is to generalize and move `web_sys::HtmlElement::from` into the `buildCbClosure` function, but haven't found a traitbound on `e` that captures this. Have tried something like below, and this is obvious a `From` trait in the wrong direction. The other direction is like an general upcast from different subtypes of `web_sys::HtmlElement`:

---

```
fn buildCbClosure<T : From<web_sys::HtmlElement>>(mut t : T) -> Closure<dyn FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent)> {
    let mut elem = web_sys::HtmlElement::from(t);
    let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
        handleButtonClick(&event);
        elem.set_text_content(Some("Text - Klik"));
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
    a
}
```

Gives:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `web_sys::HtmlElement: std::convert::From<T>` is not satisfied
--> src/lib.rs:59:20
|
59 |     let mut elem = web_sys::HtmlElement::from(t);
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<T>` is not implemented for `web_sys::HtmlElement`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of the `From` trait is `Into`. [`Into<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) is automatically implemented for a type `O`, if a `From<O>` implementation exists for `T`.

```rust
fn buildCbClosure(e : impl Into<web_sys::HtmlElement>) -> Closure<dyn FnMut(web_sys::MouseEvent)> {
    let mut e = e.into(); // `e` is an HtmlElement.
}
```

Now, any `t` that can be passed to `HtmlElement::from(t)` can be passed directly to `buildCbClosure(t)`.

Comment: Great works, thanks. Actually could be replaced with trait on `Element` level - `impl Into<web_sys::Element>`